# 3D Matplot with multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, 3d

I am trying to create a 3D surface in Python. My function is this:

```
def f(x,y):
    u = x+y 
    v = x-y
    s = x*y
    return max(u,v,s)
```

However when plotting it, using the standard method of `Z = f(X,Y)` and `X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)`, I receive the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I looked into `np.where` but this only allows for a choice of 2 different outputs, and I need a possible 3 different:  `u`, `v` or `s`.

Is there a way to make 3D plot without the meshgrid?
What could I do?

Comment: Try this inside `f(x, y)`: `return np.maximum(u, np.maximum(v, s))`.

Comment: Your problem is not `np.meshgrid`, your problem is `max(…)` in the function body.  Swag2198 advice is excellent.